# How to deal with Google analytic track event?

Tags: google-analytics

Track onclick event with param:

```
   <input name="submit" type="button" onclick="_gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’, ‘Widget Tab’, ‘Click’, ‘Hotels’]);">Submit</input>
```

Does anybody knows y this code doesn't work?

I have read the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide) and I can find any.

Comment: Have you try this plugin? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna

Comment: The short answer is: Your form will submit before the _gaq.push is given enough time to fire the _trackEvent request. See this answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461293/using-jquery-for-google-analytics-event-tracking-of-form-submits/19461995#19461995